# amp-ad on canonical amp pages (adsense and GAM)

Tags: amp-html, adsense, google-dfp, google-ad-manager

I'm converting one of my websites to AMP-only also known as Canonical AMP. Firstly to reduce the code base and secondly to just see if it can be done. I've hit a snag when it comes to ads, as AMP-ads from Google Adsense seem to be made for "mobile" only.

So, does anyone know if it's a legitimate case to use the **media** attribute on the amp-ad tag when using Adsense?

The reason I'm asking is that the "responsive" ad code from Adsense uses

```
<amp-ad width="100vw" height=320 ...
```

i.e. the width always hogs 100% of the viewport which makes it really nice for mobile with the edge-to-edge ads, but look ridiculous for desktop, especially as I have a two-colum-layout in desktop mode, making the layout look crazy.

My thought was then to use a fixed 728x90 adsense ad for the desktop, adding the media attribute to the amp-ad tag like so:

```
media="min-width([$desktop_width])"
```

(where $desktop_width is an arbitrary width where my layout switches to desktop mode i.e. two-col-layout) and the regular responsive ad for

```
media ="max-width([$desktop_width] - 1)"
```

If you wonder what the "media"-attribute is, see common attributes on amp-tags on amp.dev website.

So, therein lie my questoin. Is this an OK approach? I'll thus have two amp-ad tags right after oneanother but one is shown when viewport is of width => desktop_width and the other when it's smaller than that. Never at the same time of course.

If not, I'd have to go the GAM way (Google Ad Manager, a.k.a DFP) which is of course doable, but I'd then loose out on the nice features of the responsive ads as GAM needs a fixed setting for all its ads, even if it allows for a wide range of fixed value. GAM would mean more work for me + a little worse UX for the end user as the edge-to-edge ads are not easy to achieve = bad on the balance of it.

Answer (score -1):

Define the `width` and the `height` to match the aspect ration you'd want for the ad and then add the `layout="intrinsic"` which will scale the ad 100% when on mobile or smaller than its size and it will scale  100% of its original size, so if the ad's size is 500px, the max-width will be 500px, so it won't be distorted on desktop.

```
  <amp-ad width="250"
          height="250" 
          type="foo"
          layout="intrinsic"    
          >
</amp-ad>
```